# Excel VBA - Is it possible to increment index across multiple sheets? (incrementing one row at a time, indexing one row from each sheet)

Tags: excel, vba, increment

I have 4 sheets and a data sheet in another workbook. I want to increment numbers for index for every row I am retrieving from in the 4 sheets as you can see in the pictures I have inserted. (incrementing the index one row at a time, indexing one row from each sheet in sequence)
This is my code which can only increment rows within sheet.

```
    Sub IncrementIndexesAcrossSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim lastRowIndex As Long
    
    ' Initialize rowIndex to 1
    rowIndex = 1
    
    ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' Skip sheets without data
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells) > 0 Then
            ' Set the dataRange to the appropriate column (Column B in this case)
            Set dataRange = ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
            
            ' Loop through each cell in the dataRange
            For Each cell In dataRange
                ' Set the value of the Index column (Column A) to the current rowIndex
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = rowIndex
                ' Increment the rowIndex
                rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            Next cell
            
            ' Update lastRowIndex with the last used index on the current sheet
            lastRowIndex = rowIndex - 1
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

This is the sample data:

[image]

This is the output I want:
Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Sheet3:

[image]

Sheet4:

[image]

I am new to VBA and I have tried searching for multiple solutions but all came down to either incrementing within the sheet or just in a cell across multiple sheets. Please do help as I would really like to learn how to code such a task in VBA. My previous question was closed so I am opening a new one with better clarity.

Comment: How are your sheets built? In sheet3 for example you want it to be row9 but in your sample data row 9 is nothing like "39000 credit" / "AKJ"? Or is it just going through your amount of sheets 1 -> 2 -> 3- > etc. until each row has a number in said order? And what if sheet 1 has 10 while the others have for example 5 rows only? Does it keep getting the increment of 1+4*i?

Comment: in sheet 3 in general for column "Credit" is the sum of each unique batch from the credit in sample data. How sheet 2 and 3 works is that it takes only the 1st row of each unique batch (sort of representing the batch). Sheet 1 is based on macro run in which this case 1st run time is denoted as 1 if subsequent runs it takes the last used number if we assume 2nd run on macro it will be denoted as 50 increment from sheet 4 last data row 49. Im not sure if this explains.

Comment: Is that question any different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131596/excel-vba-is-it-possible-to-increment-index-across-multiple-sheets ?

Comment: it was closed and I am really stuck at this part. I am new here and from what I see closed questions means no one can really answer

Comment: Ok so we're clear that it goes Sheet 1 -> Sheet 2 -> Sheet 3 -> Sheet 4 (and back to Step 1) regardless of where the data is coming from. But what if any of the sheets have fewer rows, does it then go Sheet 1 - > Sheet 2 -> Sheet 3 -> Sheet 1 (because 4 has fewer rows) basically skipping 4 so you can't apply the logic I mentioned of "1+4*i"?

Comment: it is suppose to use last number recorded to increment regardless of less rows or not

Comment: is the fact that you have a data sheet in another workbook relevant for this question? (thinking I may be missing something)

Comment: for my actual data there is however in this case i have them all in one place to do trial and error

Comment: can we say that you want to add one new row to each sheet (sheet1 to sheet4), with the next index value on the sheet?

Comment: yes your correct its something similar

Comment: I cannot see the method why on Sheet4 after index=4 there are 5,6,7 and then on Sheet2 continues with index=8. What defines the changing of the Sheet in the numbering sequence. This has to be coded?

Comment: in sheet4 im was told  to duplicate the rows in each batch becoz of changes to account segment 1 and 5 as the receiver did not input their respective data in. so thats why in this case you can see in batch 1 there are 4 rows instead of original 2 with some of its column values switched around. (the duplicated are denoted as "R" in column "Party Type")

Comment: I don't see any logic we can put behind this with it repeating on sheet4 4 times to then continue back as normal. If that's to be done manually, then you'd be stuck having to change everything all over again for the order to be correct. Even with the "R", rowindex 5 doesn't have "R" and is immediately after 4 on the same sheet instead of going to sheet 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a less convoluted way of doing this but here's my attempt, not taking in account your manual editing that has no logic behind the row numbers.

This checks what the total amount of rowindexes is and iterates over the (useful) sheets until the total amount of rows is reached.

```
Sub IncrementIndexesAcrossSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, shIndex As Long, totalShts As Long
    Dim rowIndex As Long, totalRows As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        totalShts = .Sheets.Count
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
        For Each ws In .Sheets
            shIndex = shIndex + 1
            ' Skip sheets without data
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells) > 0 Then
                ' Set the dataRange to the appropriate column (Column B in this case)
                totalRows = totalRows + ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1 'taking account for headers
            End If
            dict(shIndex) = shIndex 'adding the sheet indexes to a dictionary to keep track which ones
                                    'are to be used without having to recheck
        Next ws
        shIndex = 1
        Do While rowIndex < totalRows
            If Not dict.Exists(shIndex) Then 'Don't want to accidentally add it with that weird dictionary "bug"
            Else
                With .Sheets(shIndex)
                    lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    If .Range("A" & lRow).Offset(1, 1) <> "" Then
                        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                        .Range("A" & lRow).Offset(1).Value = rowIndex
                    Else
                        dict.Remove shIndex 'sheet is all filled out
                    End If
                End With
            End If
            shIndex = shIndex + 1
            If shIndex > totalShts Then shIndex = 1 'don't go over the Sheets.Count
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

If there's actually any concrete logic for it to be 4-> 7 on sheet4, I'll try to implement it.

**Edit:** After some back and forth with OP, got some logic to implement the continuation on sheet4 before going back to its original order with the distribution number:

```
Sub IncrementIndexesAcrossSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, shIndex As Long, totalShts As Long
    Dim rowIndex As Long, totalRows As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim distriNum
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        totalShts = .Sheets.Count
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
        For Each ws In .Sheets
            shIndex = shIndex + 1
            ' Skip sheets without data
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells) > 0 Then
                ' Set the dataRange to the appropriate column (Column B in this case)
                totalRows = totalRows + ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1 'taking account for headers
            End If
            distriNum = Application.Match("Distribution Number*", ws.Rows(1), 0)
            If IsError(distriNum) Then distriNum = 0 'If it is 0 = no Distribution Number, otherwise column number
            dict(shIndex) = distriNum 'adding the sheet indexes to a dictionary to keep track which ones
                                    'are to be used without having to recheck
        Next ws
        shIndex = 1
        Do While rowIndex < totalRows
            If Not dict.Exists(shIndex) Then 'Don't want to accidentally add it with that weird dictionary "bug"
            Else
                With .Sheets(shIndex)
                    lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    distriNum = dict(shIndex)
                    If .Range("A" & lRow).Offset(0, 1) <> "" Then
                        Do While distriNum > -1
                            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                            .Range("A" & lRow).Value = rowIndex
                            If distriNum = 0 Then
                                distriNum = -1
                            ElseIf .Cells(lRow + 1, distriNum).Value = 1 Or .Cells(lRow + 1, distriNum).Value = "" Then
                                distriNum = -1
                            Else
                                lRow = lRow + 1
                            End If
                        Loop
                    Else
                        dict.Remove shIndex 'sheet is all filled out
                    End If
                End With
            End If
            shIndex = shIndex + 1
            If shIndex > totalShts Then shIndex = 1 'don't go over the Sheets.Count
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

This will now check if there's a column with "Distribution Number" in the sheet and continue on said sheet until the next distribution number changes back to 1 and moves forward from there. Used the pre-existing dictionary to pass along the possible column number for the distribution logic.

Comment: in business context there are provider and receiver. for the first 2 rows are information about provider and the next 2 rows is the receiver. i was told some receiver did not input their account information in which is why there are duplicates. however if you look carefully the duplicated rows has switched values (debit -> credit and account 1st value and 5th). As the 4 rows are still within the same batch number 1, the number is then labeled as 4 -> 7. This will then go on for each batch. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: I did see the switched values in your edited rows but I don't see a way to automate the output properly according to the provider/receiver, how you can see which is which, what goes where, etc.

Comment: is it possible where the code detects the distribution number then increment within? Since each batch starts from 1 for the distribution number.

Comment: Hmm, so we need to search for "Distribution Number" in the headers and if found, take account for that. Will it always be called that?

Comment: yes it will be that header.

Comment: Gave an edit, should continue as you wish now :) Just make sure you add your "missing lines" before running the code as I did not implement deleting pre-existing numbers.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize rowIndex to 1 + max(rowIndex) instead of 1

```
RowIndex = 1 + WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), Worksheets(2).Range("A:A"), Worksheets(3).Range("A:A"), Worksheets(4).Range("A:A"))
```

at the beginning (before the loop) and in the loop use `RowIndex = RowIndex + 1`